# Callback функции в C++

Tags: c++, callback

Я хотел бы удостовериться, что пишу все правильно и адекватно. Подскажите пожалуйста какие ошибки присутствуют в коде и желательно советы, как сделать правильно.

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;


class Point {
private:
    int xPos, yPos;
public:
    Point(int x, int y) : xPos(x), yPos(y) { }
    Point() : Point(0,0) { }
    int x() { return xPos; }
    int y() { return yPos; }
    void setX(int x) { this->xPos = x; }
    void setY(int y) { this->yPos = y; }
};

class Square {
private:
    void(*callBackFunc)(Point point);
    Point posLeftUp;
public:
    Square(){}
    Square(Point pos) : posLeftUp(pos) {}
    //Имитация движения квадрата по окну
    void Move(char key) {
        if (key == 'A')
            posLeftUp.setX(posLeftUp.x() - 2);
        else if (key == 'D')
            posLeftUp.setX(posLeftUp.x() + 2);
        else if (key == 'W')
            posLeftUp.setY(posLeftUp.y() + 2);
        else if (key == 'S')
            posLeftUp.setY(posLeftUp.y() - 2);
        callBackFunc(posLeftUp);
    }
    void setCallbackFunc(void(*fn)(Point point)) {
        callBackFunc = fn;
    }
};
//Имитация окна
class MainWindow {
private:
    static void getPosition(Point point);
    Square square;
public:
    MainWindow() {
        Point pos(10, 10);
        square = Square(pos);
        square.setCallbackFunc(getPosition);
        square.Move('A');
        square.Move('D');
        square.Move('W');
        square.Move('S');
    }
};

void MainWindow::getPosition(Point point){
        cout << point.x() << " : " << point.y() << endl;
}

int main() {
    MainWindow test;
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Вот некоторые моменты, о которых я могу высказаться.

В определении класса я бы сначала указал `public`, так как это является интерфейсом класса.

```
class Point {
public:
    Point(int x, int y) : xPos(x), yPos(y) { }
    Point() : Point(0,0) { }
    int x() { return xPos; }
    int y() { return yPos; }
    void setX(int x) { xPos = x; }
    void setY(int y) { yPos = y; }
private:
    int xPos;
    int yPos;
};
```

---

Не объединяйте декларации в одну строку:

```
    // плохо:
    // int xPos, yPos; 

    // хорошо:
    int xPos;
    int yPos;
```

---

В `setX` и `setY` не используйте `this`:

```
void setX(int x) { xPos = x; }
void setY(int y) { yPos = y; }
```

---

Используйте `switch` в `Move()`. Он сюда очень хорошо вписывается.

```
void Move(char key) {
    switch(key)
    {
    case 'A': posLeftUp.setX(posLeftUp.x() - 2); break;
    case 'D': posLeftUp.setX(posLeftUp.x() + 2); break;
    case 'W': posLeftUp.setY(posLeftUp.y() + 2); break;
    case 'S': posLeftUp.setY(posLeftUp.y() - 2); break;
    }

    callBackFunc(posLeftUp);
}
```

---

Используйте `const` переменные, где они не должны меняться. Компилятор поможет вам избежать глупых ошибок:

```
void Move(const char key) {
```

---

В `main()` можно убрать `return 0;`. Когда `main()` достигнет конца, и `return` при этом отсутствует, то `return 0;` будет подразумеваться автоматически.

---

Под "Отделять объявления от определений в классе", о чём упомянул @Andrey, имеется ввиду создание отдельных файлов для объявления класса и для определения его методов. Взять за пример ваш `class Square`:

Создадим два файла: `square.hpp` и `square.cpp`.

`square.hpp`:

```
#ifndef SQUARE_HPP
#define SQUARE_HPP

#include <functional>
#include "Point.hpp"   // Файл, содержащий объявление класса Point

class Square {
public:
    Square();
    Square(const Point pos);
    void Move(const char key);
    void setCallbackFunc(std::function<void(const Point p)>);

private:
    std::function<void(const Point p)> callBackFunc;
    Point posLeftUp;
};

#endif //SQUARE_HPP
```

В этом файле мы объявили класс `Square`, то есть перечислили его методы и члены. Этого достаточно для того, чтобы знать как использовать этот класс где-либо ещё в другом месте.

Вот эта конструкция называется Header guard ("страж заголовка" - *так это будет по-русски?*)

```
#ifndef SQUARE_HPP
#define SQUARE_HPP

// ...

#endif //SQUARE_HPP
```

Она предотвращает многократное вложение этого `hpp` файла в один и тот же `cpp` файл при компиляции.

Детали же того, как реализованы данные методы поместим во второй файл

`square.cpp`:

```
#include "square.hpp"

Square::Square() : callBackFunc(nullptr)
{}

Square::Square(const Point pos) :
    callBackFunc(nullptr),
    posLeftUp(pos)
{}

void Square::Move(const char key)
{
    switch(key)
    {
    case 'A': posLeftUp.setX(posLeftUp.x() - 2); break;
    case 'D': posLeftUp.setX(posLeftUp.x() + 2); break;
    case 'W': posLeftUp.setY(posLeftUp.y() + 2); break;
    case 'S': posLeftUp.setY(posLeftUp.y() - 2); break;
    }

    if(callBackFunc)
    {
        callBackFunc(posLeftUp);
    }
}

void Square::setCallbackFunc(std::function<void(const Point p)> fn)
{
    callBackFunc = fn;
}
```

Таким образом мы отделяем интерфейс класса от реализации его методов.

---

Кстати, класс `Point` на самом деле мог бы быть просто структурой, так как его приватные члены `xPos` и `yPos` полностью доступны для чтения и записи через методы, которые вы определили. `setX()` и `setY()` не выполняют никакой дополнительной работы, то есть, здесь нет никакой выгоды в том, чтобы прятать `x` и `y` как приватные члены:

```
struct Point{
    Point() : x(0), y(0) {};
    Point(const int x, const int y) : x(x), y(y) {};
    int x;
    int y;
};
```

Другое дело, если бы мы обязали `setX()` и `setY()` выполнять проверку переданных значений, то прятать `x` и `y` как приватные было бы оправданно:

```
void Point::setX(const int val)
{
    constexpr int min_value = -100;
    constexpr int max_value = 100;

    if (val < min_value || val > max_value)
    {
        // Ошибка. Переданное значение неприемлемо.
        throw std::runtime_error("setX(): значение вне диапазона");
    }

    x = val;
}
```

---

По поводу calback. Используйте инструменты из заголовка `<functional>`:

[`std::function<>`](https://ru.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/functional/function) - класс оболочка, который может держать в себе функцию.

[`std::bind()`](https://ru.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/functional/bind) - функция, привязывающая выполнение какой-либо функции к другой функции, с передачей ей аргументов, которые могут быть предопределены.

```
#include <functional>
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;


class Point {
public:
    Point(int x, int y) : xPos(x), yPos(y) { }
    Point() : Point(0,0) { }
    int x() { return xPos; }
    int y() { return yPos; }
    void setX(int x) { xPos = x; }
    void setY(int y) { yPos = y; }

private:
    int xPos;
    int yPos;

};

class Square {
public:
    Square(){}
    Square(Point pos) : posLeftUp(pos) {}
    //Имитация движения квадрата по окну
    void Move(const char key) {
        switch(key)
        {
        case 'A': posLeftUp.setX(posLeftUp.x() - 2); break;
        case 'D': posLeftUp.setX(posLeftUp.x() + 2); break;
        case 'W': posLeftUp.setY(posLeftUp.y() + 2); break;
        case 'S': posLeftUp.setY(posLeftUp.y() - 2); break;
        }

        if(callBackFunc)
        {
            callBackFunc(posLeftUp);
        }
    }

    void setCallbackFunc(std::function<void(const Point p)> fn) {
        callBackFunc = fn;
    }

private:
    std::function<void(const Point p)> callBackFunc = nullptr;
    Point posLeftUp;
};
//Имитация окна
class MainWindow {
private:
    static void getPosition(Point point);
    Square square;
public:
    MainWindow() {
        using namespace std::placeholders;

        Point pos(10, 10);
        square = Square(pos);
        square.setCallbackFunc(std::bind(&MainWindow::getPosition, _1));
        square.Move('A');
        square.Move('D');
        square.Move('W');
        square.Move('S');
    }
};

void MainWindow::getPosition(Point point){
        cout << point.x() << " : " << point.y() << endl;
}

int main() {
    MainWindow test;
}
```

Comment: Отделять объявления от определений в классе. Ещё бы не делать using std

Comment: @Andrey, Вы правы. Добавьте свой ответ. Я всё не усмотрел.

Comment: Вместо `std::bind(&MainWindow::getPosition, _1)` можно просто `getPosition`. Еще, на `x()` и  `y()` не хватает `const`. И, имхо, некоторые советы очень субъективные, типа 1 (public перед private), 2 (одна переменная на строку), 5 (const на параметрах).

Comment: @HolyBlackCat, Советы "одна переменная на строку" и const на параметрах я взял из книги `A Tour of C++` за авторством Бьярне. Книга, собственно, рекомендована на [SO](https://stackoverflow.com/a/388282/1418463)

Comment: Если это сказал Страуструп, это еще не значит, что это истина в последней инстанции (имхо). :)

Comment: @HolyBlackCat, я уважаю ваше мнение, но считаю, что мои советы далеко не субъективные, так как "субъективный" означает "отличающийся личным мнением". Эти же советы я не раз встречал на SO и Code Review, причём они давались пользователями со значительным количеством репутации. Ну да ладно, у каждого может быть своё мнение, и каждый по-своему прав.

Comment: @Andrey вы не могли бы показать, как правильно должно происходить отделение?

Comment: @HolyBlackCat ну Бьярне точно из топ 10 авторитетов. Так что мнение любого участника на этот ресурсе ниже чем его по весу)

Comment: @ПавелЕриков, посмотрите, я добавил эту информацию и кое-что ещё